# Should I create a class or a service for a number of interfaces?

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I have to create a number of interfaces, so I would like them to be separate.
Is that a good idea? Should this be done in service or class?
Also, can we use dependency injection for class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you need to describe what you are trying to do. Think of an interface as a class where all properties HAVE to be implemented (with exceptions). Classes and interfaces are representations of data, a service, manipulates that data in a meaningful way and can be injected into a component. so that question is rather wide. I would recommend completing this https://angular.io/tutorial tutorial, as it covers the questions you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use interface to define a contract, with the request and response of a method and your respective properties, based on this contract you can have multiple implementations that will encapsulate the logic, abstracting all business rules, so who is calling your operation. Don't knew how is processed, only the input and output of it. Using dependency inject you will reduce the coupling, Dependency injection is one form of the broader technique of inversion of control.
A client who wants to call some services should not have to know how to construct those services. Instead, the client delegates to external code (the injector). In Java, interfaces is the key this.